# How do I call object method without parentheses

Tags: javascript

I have following object. And I want to call object method without parentheses.

```
let obj = {
    'a': 1,
    'm': 1,
    'b': function () {
        let pc = 2013;
        if (pc >= 1000) return 3.4;
    }
};

result = obj['a'];    //1
result = obj['b'];    //f
result = obj['b']();  //3.4
```

How do I do that?

Comment: please add an example

Comment: is this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get what you are looking for ? getter/setters ?

Comment: @NinaScholz That question didn't answer my question. What are you flag to wrong question?

Comment: @kyore, please see edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use accessor methods like this:

```js
let obj = {
    'a': 1,
    'm': 1,
     get b () {
        let pc = 2013;
        if (pc >= 1000) return 3.4;
    }
};

console.log(obj.b)
```